# @react-native-firebase\dynamic-links cannot find symbol

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am getting the following error after using `npm install @react-native-firebase/dynamic-links`. I am not able to solve this issue, any solutions?

```
D:\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\dynamic-links\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\dynamiclinks\ReactNativeFirebaseDynamicLinksModule.java:227: error: cannot find symbol
                    Bundle linkUtmParameters = linkData.getUtmParameters();
                                                       ^
  symbol:   method getUtmParameters()
  location: variable linkData of type PendingDynamicLinkData
D:\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\dynamic-links\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\dynamiclinks\ReactNativeFirebaseDynamicLinksModule.java:458: error: cannot find symbol
                                      pendingDynamicLinkData.getUtmParameters()))));
                                                            ^
  symbol:   method getUtmParameters()
  location: variable pendingDynamicLinkData of type PendingDynamicLinkData
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_dynamic-links:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the version of `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links` are not the same. So make sure your project contains the same version of `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links`.